# how to know how many query jobs is submitted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, data-partitioning

I am working on a pipeline that takes data and do some partitioning on it, I am trying to load some data into bq table on gcp, but I got `Too many partitions produced by query, allowed 4000, query produces at least 10000 partitions`, I understand that it's a limitation by bq, and have found multiple purposed solutions to create a cluster on the data or partition by week instead of day, The problem is that I have no visibility on the data itself, I can not do this. if any other ideas are there please help.

Also, for sake of investigation and analysis, how to know how many big query jobs is submitted? is there a way to get the number of bq jobs submitted by specific dataflow?

Thannks

Answer (score 0):

You can view the jobs created by a particular Dataflow job by navigating to the Google Cloud Console and clicking through to the Dataflow Job UI. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#viewing_the_log_of_launched_jobs) is the relevant documentation with screenshots.